# Idea treats 'Ctrl + Slash' as 'Ctrl + Period' in hotkeys

Tags: intellij-idea, fedora, gnome

So I've just migrated to Fedora Linux and ran over this problem when using my Idea. I have a notebook (no numpad) and I previously used the very same Idea (Ultimate, latest) with Win10 on this very same notebook and did not experience this.

I use default English layout. In the lower row of QWERTY, to the right there is <kbd>/</kbd> button which is also <kbd>?</kbd> with shift. It works as expected anywhere else, but in Idea, when I use it as a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> shortcut it actually treats it as a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> Thus, instead of commenting selected block of code, it collapses it. I checked it in Settings -> Keymap and this is exactly how Idea interprets it.

Is there any way to change this back to normal? I don't really want to rebind this hotkey as I'm used to it by now.

Comment: Create your own personal keyboard map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting a workaround that helped me.
So the bug i'm experiencing is [this one](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=296427) and it's weird how the bug is still there.

So in my case it didn't work as expected because I had Russian keyboard layout set as first. Switching Russian to second and English to first fixed the problem for me. That's not really a 'solution', rather than a 'workaround', but it worked for me.

Comment: I had a same problem on Ubuntu 21.10. Moved English to be first layout, restarted Intellij and it works. Thanks!