# Bug on Intellij keymap + Scala + Hotkey CTRL + Slash

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using linux mint in a dell latitude E5470. The comments shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>  is not working.

I checked [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897136/intellij-idea-hotkey-for-comment-does-not-work-with-scala) and realize that the problem is different

1. Intellij recognize slash when I use it individually
2. Intellij recognize CTRL when I use other combinations like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>**→**</kbd> and so on...

So, at keymap configuration I removed the previous shortcut and tried to add again. When I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> Intellij recognized as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>. So I pressed <kbd>/</kbd> individually and keymap recognized as "**Slash**". There is some crazy thing that avoid intellij recognize the combination. But is still mapping each key correctly.

It was working before and stopped to work. I restarted intellij, cleared cache and nothing helped. I am using scala plugin.

If I press <kbd>FN</kbd> + (key on left side of slash that is supposed to be ".") Intelij recognize it as colon only on shortcut windows. If I try to type the "." only it works. The same problem is not happening on eclipse. Which means the problem is not on operating system mapping.

This is a simple problem but is driving me crazy. Is not related to [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802970/idea-treats-ctrl-slash-as-ctrl-period-in-hotkeys) or [that bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=296427)

Because I went to operating system keyboard and added perfectly a shortcut/keyboard binding with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and removed it.

Comment: What has this got to do with Eclipse?

Comment: Does it happen only in Scala files? Did you install any plug-ins for IntelliJ IDEA? Does it happen with a clean IntelliJ IDEA installation after you [remove/rename IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)?

Comment: @greg-449 it does not work with eclipse

Comment: @CrazyCoder I deleted the instalation folder and also the folder ~/.IdeaIC2017.2 and reinstalled the application. The same problem happens without scala plugin on java files.